# Firefox's App object eqivalent in other browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm not a JS guy, I barely touched it only when needed
I need to make some changes to a MVC3 app, that uses JavaScript, and when I try to run it in IE, it gets errors on first line of some scripts, in code as below :

```
App.listLoan = new Function;
```

It works in FF.

What should be equivalent, or "browser safe" code for this?

---

**EDIT:**

Actually, after investigating the code more, I discovered the App object is actually defined.

In _Layout.cshtml, I have this defined:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/app.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/listEnvelope.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code in app.js is

```
/* The main component */
var App = {
init: function () {
/* ....*/
}
```

and in listEnvelope.js I have the cpde shown initially
It works in FF but not in IE

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Odds are that the problem is higher up when something tries to define `App`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(typeof App === 'undefined') {

    // no App namespace, so create one
    var App = {};   
}
```

Comment: That will make sure that `App` is defined, but may or may not put it in the right scope or have the right properties in it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, I discovered the App was actually edited (please see my edit), but the code still don't works in IE8. Any idea?